# trying to use pyglet in python but i keep running into an error

Tags: python, pyglet

I am trying to use pyglet in a framework I am working on but I keep running into an error when I run it and cant tell if im a idiot or not.

Traceback (most recent call last:
File "C:\Users\Admin3\Desktop\custom framework\main.py", line 6, in <module>
import pyglet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyglet'

I dont know if I have imported or installed it incorrectly but every time I run the code it comes back with this error, even though I have pyglet installed and have used it before. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have python pyglet specifically installed. sometimes you need to have a version thats specific to python. if that doesn't work, try making sure everything is spelled correctly. looks fine to me, but idk.

Comment: thanks tntrobber123, I just updated pip and reinstalled the recommended version of pyglet but still no luck.